# IList<string> datatype field not being incorporated into table definition asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following model class:-

```
public class EventReg
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Event Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Event Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? EventTime { get; set; }

    public IList<string> HashTags { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Registered by")]
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }

    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }             
}
```

In my Package-Manager-Console I typed `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName CampusConnect.Models.EventDBContext`(EventDBContext is my database ) to create a configuration.cs file. I didn't add any data into the seed method. then I did `add-migration initial` to create an intial.cs file which would allow my project to update my database schema. Now when I did `update-database` each field appeared in the table definition except the HashTag field. Can anyone tell me, why?

Comment: Do you expect the IList<string> HashTags to be as a field in your table?

Comment: @yes...why, is there a problem?...I am a newbie so might have missed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of HashTags property if of type IList - entity framework can't figure out how to declare it in database. So you need to help it. Basically you have two choices:

a) Make your field of string type and form it in your format (for example comma-separated string), then make additional property that will convert it to `IList<string>`:

```
public string HashTags { get; set; }
public string IList<string> HashTagsFormated 
{
    get {
       return { HashTags.Split(',').ToList(); 
    }
}
```

b) Make separate table for hash tags and link it to your EventReg table.

```
public class EventReg
{
   public EventReg()
   {
       HashTags = new HashSet<HashTag>();
   }
   //...your other fields
   public virtual ICollection<HashTag> HashTags { get; set; }
}

public class HashTag
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int HashTagID {get;set;}

    public string HashTagName {get;set;}
    public virtual EventReg EventReg { get; set; }
}
```